# Is There a Greater Than and Not Equal to sign?

Tags: notation

If I want to say "$n$ is greater than or equal to $k$," I can say $n \geq k$.
If I want to say "$n$ is not greater than or equal to $k$," I can say $n \ngeq k$.

What if I want to say "$n$ is greater than **and** not equal to $k$?"  (In other words, $n > k$ **and** $n \neq k$).  If I'm stating that "$n$ is greater than **and** not equal to $k$," might it be better to just state it as two separate conditions rather than using one symbol (if one exists).

Comment: If $n>k$ then $n\neq k$...

Comment: Obviously.  But what I'm looking for is dependent on the specific context.  One example may be if I'm trying to prove that $n \geq k$, If I find this that this statement is false, I may want to say $n \ngeq k$ rather than $n < k$.

Comment: Note that for non-total orders, $n \ngeq k$ is not equivalent to $n < k$. However, $n > k$ always implies $n \neq k$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well since $n > k \implies n \ne k$ then just say $n > k$.  The $n \ne k$ will be implied and need not be stated at all.

Comment: So there is absolutely not a symbol? No formal or informal symbol that has ever been used to represent both $n \neq k$ and $n > k$?

Comment: No, because every person who has ever walked the planet had realized that if $n>k$ *means* that $n\ne k$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $n > k$ implies $n \not = k$, we find that "$n > k$ or $n \not = k$" is equivalent to simply $n \not = k$

In logic:

We have that $$n \not = k \Leftrightarrow n > k \lor n < k$$

Hence:

$$n > k \lor n \not = k \Leftrightarrow n > k \lor n > k \lor n < k\Leftrightarrow n > k \lor n < k \Leftrightarrow n \not = k$$

EDIT

I see that the exercise now has become how to write "$n > k$ or $n \not = k$". Well:

$$n > k \land n \not = k \Leftrightarrow n > k \land (n > k \lor n < k) \overset{Absorption}{\Leftrightarrow} n > k$$

Of course! If $n > k$ then $n \not = k$, and so $n \not = k$ is not adding anything to the statement $n >k$

Comment: I am very aware of the workings of first order logic, however, I do not believe it is relevant to my question at hand.

Comment: It is relevant, because he suggested a symbol:  the correct, compact way to write "$n > k$ or $n \neq k$" is "$n \neq k$".

Comment: I'm trying to write "$n > k$ and $n \neq k$."  Therefore, the (correct) logical solution of "$n \not = k \Leftrightarrow n > k \lor n < k$" does not apply to my question.

Comment: You should change the subject line then.  Writing "$n$ is greater than or not equal to $k$" means "$n > k$ or $n \neq k$".

Comment: And the way to write "n > k" and "n \ne k" is....."n > k".

Comment: My apologies, just fixed my typo in the title.

Comment: @supersmarty1234 Sorry, it was confusing; at first it looked as if you wanted the "or" statement. Anyway, I just added the "and" analysis as well.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, that's what $\;>\;$ is for. However, if you want to draw special attention to the fact that $\;\neq\;$ applies, then you can use $\;\gneqq \;$ or $\;\gvertneqq \;.$

From the mid 1970s through the early 1990s, I sometimes used (in notes, in homework assignments, etc.) handwritten forms of these symbols and their "less than" versions $\;\lneqq\;$ and $\;\lvertneqq \,,\;$ and they were also sometimes used on the blackboard by the mathematics teachers I had during this period.

Incidentally, even more commonly used back then was the corresponding proper subset relation $\subsetneqq \,,\;$ since the meaning of $\;\subset\;$ varies among authors, with some using this for "subset or equal" and others using this for "proper subset". By using $\;\subsetneqq\;$ for "proper subset" and using $\;\subseteqq \;$ or $\;\subseteq \;$ for "subset or equal", there is no chance of ambiguity.

For what it's worth, these symbols are available in the LaTeX-based software I use, [Scientific Workplace](https://www.mackichan.com/index.html?products/swp.html). However, they do not appear to be available in [MathType](https://web.archive.org/web/20180422192250/http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/) (which I sometimes have to use for work-related stuff), but maybe doing something like [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20180425072848/http://dessci.com/en/support/mathtype/tsn/tsn117.htm) will locate them. A quick google image search led me to the Mathematics Stack Exchange question [What does this “double less than or equals to” sign mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98143/what-does-this-double-less-than-or-equals-to-sign-mean), where both $\;\gneqq \;$ and $\;\lneqq\;$ are included in a chart for AMS codes for various inequality symbols.